# Reusing & Parameters Passing In Angular2 Component, in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: angular, visual-studio-2015

I am publishing this question after deep search. There are similar type of questions but none of them solved the issue.Mainly I followed Angular2 Document. And I am completely new to Angular2.

[Angular2 Parameters Passing](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/components/app_structure/passing_data_into_components.html)

My problem is,

1. How to reuse the same angular2 component in the same page, by passing different parameters, let's say giving an unique name to the component.

ex: Create two same type components, in two different labels, as Component1 & Component2

It renders the component, but, it doesn't catch the params I pass.

**Component.ts**

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'txt-comp',
  template: '<h1>Hello, This is {{name}}!</h1>',
})

export class txtComponent{
  @Input() name: string;

 ngOnInit()
 {
   console.log(this.name);
 }

}
```

**Home.aspx**

```
 <txt-comp [name]="Welcome"></txt-comp>
```

When rendered the page, this displays only,

```
**Hello, This is**
```

When I create two instances, as

```
 <txt-comp [name]="Welcome1"></txt-comp>
 <txt-comp [name]="Welcome2"></txt-comp>
```

render only one instance.

Can Somebody explain me the wrong I did and the right way to achieve this ?

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

add single quotes, angular is expecting that "Welcome1" and "Welcome2" are variables

```
<txt-comp [name]="'Welcome1'"></txt-comp>
<txt-comp [name]="'Welcome2'"></txt-comp>
```

Comment: Console prints undefined !

Comment: try implementing the OnInit interface: 
export class txtComponent implements OnInit {}

Comment: Here is a stackblitz link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5gcdkn, tell me if the link does not work, i don't really have experience with sharing demo code

Comment: This worked ! But, why did you use separation, for app and txt. Let's imagine, that I want to create txt-comp in different locations in the same index.html page. That's the thing I want to do. But, in this case, my-app component, by default inherit two txt-comps. But, instead of my-app, I want to directly call txt-comp, by passing parameters, in different locations, in the index.html, whenever I want to. I tried what you have done and it worked, but the exact thing I need to do is call component uniquely. :) No two txt-comps at the same time.

Comment: Ex, in my index page, at the top I want to call <txt-comp txtName="Welcome1"> & at the bottom, <txt-comp txtName="Welcome2">

Comment: You need a single entry-point for your angular app, just look at you app.component.html as your index.html page. Just put everything you wanted to show on your index.html page inside the app.component.html

Answer (score 0):

As `J Pinxten` mentioned you can do it

```
<txt-comp [name]="'Welcome1'"></txt-comp>
<txt-comp [name]="'Welcome2'"></txt-comp>
```

or

```
<txt-comp name="Welcome1"></txt-comp>
<txt-comp name="Welcome2"></txt-comp>
```

When you are using `[]` it expect to use an expression or a variable in your ts code or a value of that type, since you want to pass string you need to use `"'Welcome1'"`, or using it without binding

Just pay attention since `name` is a known attribute on html elements it might make some confusions, so it's better to use another name like `componentName` or ..

Comment: I tried both ways. but the same out put. the parameter, passed is not caught at the component class. prints in console, undefined. and used a different name instead 'name'

Comment: @TharakaMadhusanka see Pinxten comment

Answer (score 0):

First of all, pleas stop using the word 'Parameter', in Angular world, when you say parameters that means, you are trying to deal with params array ( query parameters or similar ), so you are just trying to pass an input to your component, so stick to that terminology.

Following should work

Solution one, in your component

```
name: string = 'Welcome'
```

And in your template use

```
<txt-comp [name]="name"></txt-comp>
```

OR

use this directly in your template ( Without brackets )

```
<txt-comp name="Welcome"></txt-comp>
```

OR 
use this with bracket

```
<txt-comp [name]="'Welcome'"></txt-comp>
```